# Is there a way to extract a data frame from a list, and assign the data frame to an object with a dynamic name?

Tags: r

I have a list containing many named data frames. I am trying to find a way to extract each data frame from this list. Ultimately, the goal is to assign each data frame in the list to an object according to the name that it has in the list, allowing me to reference the data frames directly instead of through the list (eg. dataframe instead of LIST[[dataframe]])

Here is an example similar to what I am working with.

```
library(googlesheets4)
inst.pkg("dplyr")
library(dplyr)
gs4_deauth()

TABLES <- list("Test1", "Test2")
readTable <- function(TABLES){
  TABLES <- range_read(as_sheets_id("SHEET ID"),sheet = TABLES)
  TABLES <-as.data.frame(TABLES)
  TABLES <- TABLES %>%
  transmute(Column1= as.character(Column1), Column2 = as.character(Column2 ))
  return(TABLES)}
LIST <- lapply(TABLES, readTable)
names(LIST) <- TABLES
```

I know that this could be done manually, but I'm trying to find a way to automate this process. Any advice would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `?list2env` is probably what you're looking for. But this is generally frowned upon as bad practice. What if you want to apply some function to every data.frame? Now you'll have to do it one-by-one, or try to gather them back into a list before applying the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `named_dfs` is a named list where each element is a dataframe you can use the `assign` function to achieve your goal.

```
Map(assign, names(named_dfs), named_dfs, pos = 1)
```

For each name, it assigns (equivalent to `<-` operator) the corresponding dataframe object.

```
Map(function(x, y) assign(x, y, envir = globalenv()), names(named_dfs), named_dfs)
```

Should also work.

Comment: I don't think this works. You're not assigning to the global environment.

Comment: Hello, thank you a lot for the quick response. I actually managed to work something out using the assign function that you mentioned. Instead of map, I ended up using a for loop. Here's what I ended up doing if you want to see. 

for(L in TABLES){
  assign(names(LIST[L]),LIST[[L]])
}